# Where does the energy loss in cycling go proportionally?

Tags: physics

If you are biking on level ground with no wind, I understand that there are losses inherent in your activity which you provide effort to overcome  (if you want to maintain a steady speed):

- Air/wind resistance
- Rolling resistance
- Friction losses
- ?

I am wondering if there has been any significant analysis into what *percentage* of the overall energy exertion goes to which loss. Something like "70% of the energy loss is due to X, 15% to Y" etc.

I know that this will vary based on the type of bike, tire pressure, posture, speed, wind speed, etc, but I am curious if there has ever been an in-depth analysis into the breakdown of energy loss in cycling.

I care about far more than just drag, which is the only variable the related question addresses.

Comment: An interesting energy loss you haven't listed - sound. Sound is a form of energy loss as much as heat, so all the noise your chain makes as it goes round a derailleur is energy being bled from the system. A minute amount, but an amount none-the-less.

Comment: Although your question isn't a direct duplicate of [How can one estimate drag for a bicycle?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/9938/7309), the answers pretty much would be.

Comment: You need to add drive-train to your list.

Comment: @SGR Sound is covered by "friction losses".

Comment: @SGR - Actually, the amount of energy going into cussing out the hill you see coming can get to be quite large.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there has been tons of in depth analysis on this, and the equations are rather simple so you can answer the questions for yourself given different scenarios using the [Equations of motion for cyling](http://www.wisil.recumbents.com/wisil/MartinDocs/Validation%20of%20a%20mathematical%20model%20for%20road%20cycling.pdf)

Assuming you are on a road bike, on a flat road, with reasonable tires, the vast majority of energy is overcoming aerodynamic drag, about 70-80%

After that, the rolling resistance of the tires will be the biggest power draw, at around 20%

You will notice that doesn't leave much room for anything else! Next up would be total drivetrain losses are typically in the 2% range.

Of course as you go uphill, energy begins to be spent overcoming gravity, changing these ratios.

Comment: It should be noted that rolling losses can increase significantly on rougher roads.  Most of this energy, believe it or not, goes into jiggling the body up and down.

Comment: Does that then mean that the weight (either of the body or the bike or the complete mess) does not make that much difference?

Comment: Yes when the road is flat, and you are not accelerating, mass does not make much difference. It does increase the total resistance due to rolling resistance a bit though.